# How to Integrate Supersize Pluggin with WordPress Custom Post Types Feature Image

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

apologies if the below is incorrectly written. First time posting. Thanks in advance of any solutions.

I am trying to integrate the Supersized plugging manually with WordPress. I need it to use my defined Custom Post Type (CPT) called 'homepageslides' and take the Featured Image of a post within that CPT and pull it into the Supersize script.

My CPT 'homepagesslides' correctly works in a normal loop. Code can be seen here: **http://pastebin.com/1KqH2asD**

And I have the Supersized Pluggin working within WordPress using absolute urls. Code can be seen here:
**http://pastebin.com/jbpccWa2**

I've been trying for hours to combine the above but am yet to succeed. The slides (the bit between the square brackets) needs to be dynamically generated from the WordPress CPT.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dave

**Previous research links:**
These target a specific directory or have elements that I can't make work.

[jquery Supersize show IE error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794009/jquery-supersize-show-ie-error)

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-types-category_name

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tutorial-how-to-detect-images-automatically-with-supersized

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
slides : [
<?php 
    //query
    query_posts(array('post_type'=>'homepageslides',
                      'posts_per_page'=>'20'
                      ));

    //loop
    if(have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            //feature image
            $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
            $title = get_the_title();

            //echo slides
            echo "{image : '".$large_image_url[0]."', title : '".$title."', url : ''},";

        endwhile; 
    endif; 
?>]
```